# Safari -- Equivalent of viewport meta tag (à la Android/iOS)? I want to specify max zoom level for OS X Safari

Tags: html, macos, safari

The viewport meta tag works wonders for configuring how a webpage appears on touch devices. I can control the maximum zoom level, the pixel width of the page, and even the initial zoom level.

The reason why this is helpful is that tablet devices like iOS devices and Android devices heavily employ the concept of viewport zoom which allows the user to pinch and look at a part of a website in greater detail. The traditional web browser on a PC or Mac or laptop simply does not make use this functionality.

Until recent versions of Safari on OS X.

Safari also allows you to pinch your MacBook touchpad (and I imagine you can do this with a Magic Trackpad as well) to zoom into a webpage in exactly the same way.

Once zoomed in this way, the values of `window.innerHeight/Width` and `document.documentElement.clientHeight/Width` begin to vastly differ, and the scroll offset can be seen via `document.body.scrollTop/Left`. This would appear to mirror very closely what happens when zooming in on a touch device.

Getting back to the question at hand. While I am able to specify the `maximum-scale` for a touch device in the meta tag, this has no effect for OS X Safari... It appears to be limited to 300% zoom. I would like to be able to employ the native zoom functionality to navigate a large SVG element. This already works flawlessly on iOS...

P.S. I have tried css `@viewport` but it does not do anything and it also seems like only IE and Opera support it.